# Trying to display toast messages one after another

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-toast

Trying to display multiple Toast messages one after another, but only the last toast message gets displayed. I tried using Thread.sleep, and handlers to buffer the messages, but neither worked. Any other tips? Here's my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_cow)


        // updates the variables with these values
        Submit.setOnClickListener {
            cowName = Cow_Name.text.toString()
            cowWeight = Cow_Weight.text.toString().toIntOrNull()
            cowSex = Cow_Sex.text.toString()
            cowAge = Cow_Age.text.toString()

            showToast(cowName.toString())
            showToast(cowWeight.toString())
            showToast(cowSex.toString())
            showToast(cowAge.toString())

        }

    }
    private fun showToast(text: String)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        handler.postDelayed ({
            // Do nothing
        }, 2000)
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a SnackBar instead (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar)? I believe those will queue automatically.

Comment: but why? multiple toast seems to be a good reason to uninstall the app immediately. Consider if you can use a SnackBar or a custom dialog.

Comment: Testing purposes, want to make sure certain data is being read and processed

Comment: Ok logcat and debug can be an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At minimum you should add a "delay" variable to "showToast" and move the `Toast` call to *inside* the posted `Runnable`:

```
private fun showToast(text: String, delayInMilliseconds: Int) {
    val context = this
    handler.postDelayed (
        { Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() },
        delayInMilliseconds
    )
}
```

Then you'd call it like

```
showToast(cowName.toString(), 0)
showToast(cowWeight.toString(), 1000)
showToast(cowSex.toString(), 2000)
showToast(cowAge.toString(), 3000)
```

Or whatever delay values were required to make that work.

Comment: Okay sweet, that's perfect. I thought I tried something similar before I displayed the code snippet above. Thank you!

May I ask why when I set them all to the same delayed value it doesn't work?

Comment: Well you can only show one Toast on the screen at once. And calling "postDelayed" doesn't block the "showToast" method call from completing until that delay is over; you are just posting a Runnable to a queue that will be executed later. So if you call "postDelayed" with all the same time, you'll get 4 immediate calls to "showToast" and then after some delay they will all be executed and try to show at the same time.